# What is $b$ in this formula of friction force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, notation

I have seen  a formula of friction force,$\vec{F}=-b\vec{v}$

I know $\vec{v}$ is velocity,but what is $b$?

Is it damping coefficient or friction coefficient?

Or damping coefficient or friction coefficient both refer to exactly same thing?

Comment: Friction force does not depend on body velocity. Do you mean [Stokes drag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)#Very_low_Reynolds_numbers:_Stokes'_drag) law $\mathbf {F} _{d}=-b\mathbf {v}$ in case of low Reynolds numbers ? I'm sure you can decode what $b$ includes from wiki main page about Stokes drag.

Comment: This force Ansatz is for a viscose damping (hydraulic damper) the unit of b is $~N=kg\,m/s^2=b\,m/s~$ ,$~b=[kg/s]~$